# Numeric input not reflecting

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I am using Ionic 3 along with Angular 5 and trying to use as below:

```
<ion-input type="number"><ion-input>
```

so It should reflect like this:

[image]

but when I am using above line of code then it's reflecting like normal input and can't see up and down arrow only in application but when I have created other ionic app and used exact same line then it's worked don't know why.  dependencies I am using like:

```
"@angular/common": "5.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
"@angular/core": "5.0.3",
"@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
"@angular/http": "5.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
"@ionic-native/date-picker": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
"@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
"@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
```

Anyone can suggest me what to do?

Comment: try this <ion-input type="number"></ion-input> and up and down arrow will be shwon on desktop browser

Comment: Are you sure? I can see the arrows https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-gseliz?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html .. Which device? or browser?

Comment: @SurajRao yes you are right, but It's not reflecting in my case (in my application), I have also checked with new ionic app it's working there that;s why I have posted my dependencies.

Comment: can you post as text and not an image? also this image does not show `ionic-angular` version.. its incomplete?

Comment: @SurajRao I have updated my question.

Comment: the version seems fine... Is this in a browser or any device/emulator?

Comment: @SurajRao I am using android studio.